# Visual Studio 2019 DSL Toolbox (Version 4.0.0.0 from Microsoft Corporation .Net Component)

Tags: visual-studio, dsl, dsl-tools

I have built a dsl which has been working correctly for sometime. however, after recent changes to the domain model one item toolbox for a single item (all other toolbox items are functioning correctly)

The recent change was extending a classes properties on the domain model and the initial test worked correctly. After check-in and shutdown the next time i opened the project and run the vs-experimental the toolbox has de-synced.

it is visible on the toolbox and i can "manually" add the class via the DSL Explorer (right click, New xxx), and the object is displayed correctly. All other objects are working (drag and drop) from toolbox, just the single object. The problematic items displays the message "Version 4.0.0.0 from Microsoft Corporation .Net Component".
If i run vs with debug logging i get the follow output.

```
  <entry>
    <record>5050</record>
    <time>2020/03/22 22:51:02.159</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Toolbox data object</source>
    <description>Data format &apos;CF_TOOLBOXITEMCONTAINER_CONTENTS&apos; of registered toolbox item &apos;DslNamespace.DomainClassToolToolboxItem&apos; was not populated when requested.  This is a bug in the package that owns the item.</description>
  </entry>
```

I have reset toolbox, deleted tdb files and reinitialized and delete toolbox registry keys in experiment and core vs instance. still with no luck.

Has anyone seen/fix a similar issue with the toolbox? the classes can be added and displayed correctly (dsl explorer), just not via the toolbox.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with the toolbox cache.
I've tried to reset the toolbox and to delete the tdb files as you, but it's not sufficient.

The only solution that I've found is to clear the `XXXXExp` folders here:
`%localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\`
and here:
`%appdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\`